# Installed Git + EGit and Then "No Companion Library Found" Error Occurs!

Tags: macos, git, operating-system, eclipse

Trying to use git with eclipse.

Downloaded x64 bit version of Git using http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/downloads/list?can=3.

Then installed the EGit tool.

I then see:

> The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate 
>   its
>   companion shared library.

Very confused. Any help is greatly appreciated! :D

Comment: Egit ought to be in pure Java, so teoretically you wouldn't need "normal" git. (Of course I may miss something important here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be:

- an issue of right (755 not set) as in [this thread](http://vsingleton.blogspot.com/2009/09/eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable.html) (for windows, but the idea is the same for MacOs)
- or an [incorrect launcher in the eclipse.ini](http://lookfirst.com/2008/09/eclipse-341-poopy.html) (or [this thread](http://tamsler.blogspot.com/2008/10/eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable.html), although I recommend, with Eclipse3.5 or 3.6, to remove any mention of said launcher, as in this [eclipse.ini](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/3275659#3275659))

I don't think this is directly related to Git itself.

As usual, with 64bits installation, check you do have a 64bits JVM launching your 64bits Eclipse.